# Using HAProxy for transparent forwarding and selective redirection

Tags: haproxy

I'm setting up a temporary haproxy instance to help test a new back-end for an iphone app. Instead of having a specially produced app or a jailbreak, my plan is to set up a proxy that all phone data will go through, but have it match host headers and forward them to the new servers that are not yet live. In short, I want haproxy to act like an open proxy, apart from on some specific host names. Matching the host names and forwarding them is working perfectly, but I can't seem to make the open proxy bit work. I'm using a stock haproxy 1.4.18 package on Ubuntu Precise with stock global settings, plus these proxy settings:

```
frontend myapp
    bind 0.0.0.0:8080
    default_backend passthrough
    acl mydomain hdr_end(Host) .example.com
    use_backend front if mydomain

backend front
    server front 127.0.0.1:80

backend passthrough
    server ???
```

So the frontend sits on port 8080, defaulting to pushing requests to the `passthrough` backend. Prior to doing that it checks the acl to see if the request is for a hostname in my domain, and if it is, forwards it to the local app instead.

The problem is with that `passthrough` backend. I want it to pass on requests directly to the requested host, not to a local end point. The config I've put there won't work, but I don't know what it should say. For example if I do a request for `http://www.serverfault.com`, it wouldn't match my ACL, so I'd want it forwarded directly to serverfault, not to a local server. I'm not sure what directive will do this in a backend, or whether there is some frontend directive that will do it. It's more or less a no-op as far as the proxy is concerned.

(Yes I know that open proxies are bad; this is a temporary testing configuration, running interactively for only a few minutes at a time)

**Update**: I've found `option http_proxy` does exactly what I need, apart from that it doesn't do DNS lookups, only explicit IPs, so a backend like this is nearly there:

```
backend passthrough
    option http_proxy
    option httpclose
```

I know I probably could use something else, but I just happen to really like haproxy!

Comment: You could do it with a normal forwarding proxy like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). Then have the special rules for what you want to intercept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure haproxy to do this for you. The backend servers in haproxy have to be explicitly named.

Couldn't you instead just use a dedicated DNS server to direct the phone to the correct server?

Comment: This isn't true: you can have a backend containing only `option http_proxy` and no server directives and it will work. The only downside is that it won't do name lookups, only explicit IPs, making it useless as a forward proxy.

Comment: I assumed that you needed to do name resolution so I didn't mention that option.

Comment: I gave up trying to get haproxy to do this, followed your suggestion and have set up a DNS server with dnsmasq instead, and it works just fine with a 1-line config. I did look at squid, but it's a config nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

you can use haproxy as a simple http proxy, with the following configuration -

```
backend direct_forward
option httpclose
option http_proxy
```

you can read more about is [here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-option%20http_proxy)